# How can I match this pattern in haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I've got data

```
LNode(TypedL(2.72489e12,"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double"))
```

I want an anonymous function to match from this to 2.72489e12

```
myfunc (LNode(TypedL(c, d))) = c
```

gives

```
Constructor `TypedL' should have 2 arguments, but has been given 1.
```

Is my syntax with this function wrong?

Comment: The pattern looks fine to me. If the pattern isn't being accepted, is the data being accepted?

Comment: Are you sure you need the tuple syntax? That is, does writing `myfunc (LNode (TypedL c d)) = c` rather than `myfunc (LNode (TypedL(c, d))) = c` type check?

Comment: What is the definition of `LNode` and `TypedL`?  Without those we can't really tell you why the pattern match fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the way you're calling your function. In Haskell, functions and constructors are called like this:

```
function arg1 arg2 arg3
```

So, when it says it wants two arguments, it means this:

```
myfunc (LNode (TypedL c d)) = c
--                    ~~~
```

Tuples (`(a, b, c)`) are separate datatypes. They can be used as function arguments if defined, but that's generally seen as unidiomatic Haskell.